# Does Google provide a search like YQL?

Tags: yahoo, yql

I found out about YQL today, and it seems pretty useful. However, I don't really want to use something by Yahoo. Does Google provide something like YQL?

Comment: I'm interested, why are you so black-and-white with regards to the companies whose tools you wish to (not) use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Google does not offer an equivalent to YQL.

I wouldn't worry too much about "yahoo" versus "google", but instead see if the tool will help solve what you're trying to do.